Moodle 4.x failing to install via command line in Ubuntu
I am following this link to be able to setup Moodle on Ubuntu. Moodle command line instructions.  I am getting a failure at line 187 in the /lib/installlib.php.  I have put in the correct information about the DB connection (username, pw, etc). I normally install through the moodle web interface.  I am wondering if anyone has successfully installed moodle through command line interface with Moodle 4.x before??
/**
 * This is in function because we want the /install.php to parse in PHP4
 *
 * @param object $database
 * @param string $dbhsot
 * @param string $dbuser
 * @param string $dbpass
 * @param string $dbname
 * @param string $prefix
 * @param mixed $dboptions
 * @return string
 */
function install_db_validate($database, $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $prefix, 
$dboptions) {
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z_]*$/', $prefix)) {
        return get_string('invaliddbprefix', 'install');
    }
    try {
       try {
           $database->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $prefix, $dboptions);
       } catch (moodle_exception $e) {
           // let's try to create new database
            if ($database->create_database($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, 
$dboptions)) {
               $database->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $prefix, 
$dboptions);
            } else {
                throw $e;
            }
       }
       return '';
    } catch (dml_exception $ex) {
        $stringmanager = get_string_manager();
        $errorstring = $ex->errorcode.'oninstall';
        $legacystring = $ex->errorcode;
        if ($stringmanager->string_exists($errorstring, $ex->module)) {
            // By using a different string id from the error code we are separating 
   exception handling and output.
            $returnstring = $stringmanager->get_string($errorstring, $ex->module, $ex->a);
            if ($ex->debuginfo) {
                $returnstring .= '<br />'.$ex->debuginfo;
            }

            return $returnstring;
        } else if ($stringmanager->string_exists($legacystring, $ex->module)) {
        // There are some DML exceptions that may be thrown here as well as during 
normal operation.
        // If we have a translated message already we still want to serve it here.
        // However it is not the preferred way.
        $returnstring = $stringmanager->get_string($legacystring, $ex->module, $ex->a);
        if ($ex->debuginfo) {
            $returnstring .= '<br />'.$ex->debuginfo;
        }

            return $returnstring;
        }
        // No specific translation. Deliver a generic error message.
        return $stringmanager->get_string('dmlexceptiononinstall', 'error', $ex);
    }
}


What is the full and exact error message, and what is line 187?

Line 187 appears to be the database connection line, which simply means PHP can't connect to the database. So your user/pass/host/port is wrong, or the database isn't running, or it's not configured to accept connections, or there's a firewall blocking the connection.

@alex, that is what I thought. This is first time I have attempted a commandline install of moodle. I do not have browser access (yet) to client's AWS VM.  I will go back and see if I can use the postgre client itself to connect to the DB VM's default database.  Thank you for the insight.

My problem was two-fold. My client had Wide-Area Firewall (WAF) set incorrectly which prevented communication between Moodle 4.1 and the external PostgreSQL database. Then I figured out they failed to correctly install Postgres 'driver' to the VM.

Can you add these lines to config.php then copy and paste the full error message to the question
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!`

